# Remove Captcha verification on firebase phone auth in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase phone auth in flutter android.
I have uploaded App signing key certificate's SHA-256 key, upload key certificate's SHA-256, developer's PC SHA-256 key.

Yet I am getting captcha verification in phone auth.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try in real device??

Comment: Yes, the app is in production and tested on real device

Answer (score -1):

I am still in debug and didn't upload yet to store, just saw a note that *you need to have a recent version of firebase auth package.*

Make sure you have it.